# Initial slideshow shows split image

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I'm using caroufredsel which I've used many times and have never had this problem before. On Safari only the initial load of the page shows a split image - half of the first and half of the second. Like this:

[image]

The slideshow fades the the next one fine and if you go to another page and back again then it is also fine. And it only occurs on Safari. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is my html:

```
    <div class='slideshow'>
        <div class='centralised_div'>
            <div class='slideshow_inner'>
                <div class='slideshow_images'>
                    <img src='/images/ss2.jpg'/>
                    <img src='/images/ss3.jpg'/>
                    <img src='/images/ss4.jpg'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='arrow_left'><img src='/images/left_arrow.png'/></div>
            <div class='arrow_right'><img src='/images/right_arrow.png'/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".slideshow_images").carouFredSel({
                width: 940,
                height: 400,
                direction: "left",
                items: {
                    visible: 1,
                    start: "random",
                    width: 940,
                    height: 400
                },
                scroll: {
                    fx: "crossfade",
                    duration: 1000,
                    pauseOnHover: true
                },
                auto: 6000,
                prev: {
                    button: ".arrow_left",
                    key: "left"
                },
                next: {
                    button: ".arrow_right",
                    key: "right"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problems I have with carouFredSel are solved when I initialize it after window load instead of document ready. Maybe that helps you:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".slideshow_images").carouFredSel({
            width: 940,
            height: 400,
            direction: "left",
            items: {
                visible: 1,
                start: "random",
                width: 940,
                height: 400
            },
            scroll: {
                fx: "crossfade",
                duration: 1000,
                pauseOnHover: true
            },
            auto: 6000,
            prev: {
                button: ".arrow_left",
                key: "left"
            },
            next: {
                button: ".arrow_right",
                key: "right"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```